# Mysql converting milliseconds gives me 1970

Tags: mysql, date, milliseconds

When I attempt to use FROM_UNIXTIME(dateField) I get 1970...
I even tried FROM_UNIXTIMESTAMP, still no good.

I'm trying to convert milliseconds to date format.

EDIT:

```
Using FROM_UNIXTIME(`createdDate`)
    input: 1549477680843
    Output: January 01, 1970 12:00:02 AM

Using FROM_UNIXTIME(`createdDate`/1000)
input: 1549477680843
January 01, 1970 12:00:00 AM
```

Comment: If this has anything to do with an RDBMS, see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: 1549477680843 should correspond to Wednesday, February 6, 2019 6:28:00.843 PM GMT. So I agree that something looks wrong… Has anybody else been able to reproduce?

Answer (score 1):

`FROM_UNIXTIME` expects *seconds*, so you'll need to divide millisecond values by 1000.

```
FROM_UNIXTIME(dateField / 1000)
```

Comment: still no good. I load the milliseconds into DOMO as a string. using FROM_UNIXTIME now gives me feb 6th for all the dates.

Comment: Can you provide examples of your input data and your expected output?

Comment: `SELECT FROM_UNIXTIME(1549477680843/1000)` produces `2019-02-06 13:28:00.8430`. Is that what you want?

Comment: when I use FROM_UNIXTIME(`createdDate`/1000, '%h:%i %p, %D %M %Y') I get 06:28 PM, 6th February 2019. that is way off from your value.

Comment: If you want to apply formatting that's entirely up to you, it's just cosmetic, but the default format produces the correct date.

Comment: without formatting, I get: 2019-02-06 18:28:00.843000. seems 5 hours off form your value??